# RFID считыватель на планшете?

Tags: android, авторизация, terminal

Стоит задача - сделать терминал для ввода данных на планшете(Android), чтобы была идентификация пользователя, который вводит данные. Если проще, то примерно так: подходит человек к терминалу (стойка с закрепленным в специальном корпусе планшетом), прикладывает свою rfid карточку, планшет разблокировывается, и человек на планшете отмечает, выполненное задание. Эту информацию (какое задание сделано и кем сделано) планшет отправляет на сервак.

Не могу определиться с физической реализацией. Нагуглить готовые решения не получилось, хотя слышал, что есть что-то подобное. Может посоветуете что-нибудь? Кто сталкивался?

Пофиг на начинку - приложение для андроида можно будет написать. Я имею в виду конструкцию. Стойка+планшет+считыватель, и чтобы все это было на постояной запитке. Гугл что-то мне не очень помог в моем поиске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
Авторизоваться на Android-девайсе можно с помощью поддержки его NFC-технологией. Осталось только найти нужный девайс.